# audio canvas draw android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to use canvas to draw the input signal from mic in real time 
but I have a problem,
The code I am using is plotting a different signal (does not look like regular audio signals) and the visualizer is too fast .. I guess it has something to do with the duration or period but I am very new to this canvas concept ?

[image: Here is a screen shot of the output]

```
package com.example.soundvisualizer;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CDrawer extends SurfaceView

  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback

{

  private Context mContext;
  private CDrawThread mDrawThread;
  private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

  private Boolean isCreated = false;
  /** 
   * This is where you instance the drawer
   * You relly don't need to care about the parameters, they are set in the xml-layout
   * @param Apply the baseContext of you current acitivty 
   * @param AttributeSet
   */
  public CDrawer(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet)
  {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
    System.out.println("CDrawer()");
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mContext = paramContext;
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mDrawThread = new CDrawThread(mHolder, paramContext, new Handler()
    {
      public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
      {
      }
    });
    mDrawThread.setName("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    setFocusable(true);
  }

  public Boolean GetDead2()
  {
    return mDrawThread.GetDead2();
  }

  /**
   * restarts the thread
   * @param Is the thread dead?
   */
  public void Restart(Boolean paramBoolean)
  {
      if (isCreated) {
    if (mDrawThread.GetDead2().booleanValue())
    {
      mDrawThread.SetDead2(Boolean.valueOf(false));
      if ((!paramBoolean.booleanValue()) || (!mDrawThread.GetDead().booleanValue()))

      mHolder = getHolder();
      mHolder.addCallback(this);
      System.out.println("Restart drawthread");
      mDrawThread = new CDrawThread(mHolder, mContext, new Handler()
      {
        public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
        {
        }
      });
      mDrawThread.setName("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
      mDrawThread.start();
      return;
    }
    Boolean No1,No2 = true;
    while (true)
    {
      while (No2 = true)
      {

        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(10000L);
          System.out.println("Just chilling in Restart");
          No2 = false;
          mDrawThread.SetDead2(Boolean.valueOf(true));
        }
        catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
        {
          localInterruptedException.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
      }

     if (!mDrawThread.GetDead().booleanValue())
        continue;
      mHolder = getHolder();
      mHolder.addCallback(this);
      System.out.println("Restart drawthread");
      mDrawThread = new CDrawThread(mHolder, mContext, new Handler()
      {
        public void handleMessage(Message paramMessage)
        {
        }
      });
      mDrawThread.setName("" +System.currentTimeMillis());
      mDrawThread.start();
      return;
    }
      }
  }

  public void SetRun(Boolean paramBoolean)
  {
    mDrawThread.setRun(paramBoolean);
  }

  public CDrawThread getThread()
  {
    return mDrawThread;
  }

  /**
   * Called when there's a change in the surface
   */
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3)
  {
    mDrawThread.setSurfaceSize(paramInt2, paramInt3);
  }

  /**
   * Creates the surface
   */
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder)
  {
    System.out.println("surfaceCreated");
    if (mDrawThread.getRun().booleanValue())
    {
      System.out.println("11111");
      isCreated = true;
      mDrawThread.start();

    }
    while (true)
    {
      System.out.println("22222");
      Restart(Boolean.valueOf(false));
      return;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Surface destroyd
   */
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder)
  {
    int i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
      if (i == 0)
        return;
      try
      {
        mDrawThread.join();
        i = 0;
      }
      catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException)
      {
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * The Drawer Thread, subclass to cDrawer class
   * We want to keep most of this process in a background thread,
   * so the UI don't hang 
   *  @author Pontus Holmberg (EndLessMind)
   *  Email: the_mr_hb@hotmail.com
   */
  class CDrawThread extends Thread
  {
    private Paint mBackPaint;
    private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
    private short[] mBuffer;
    private int mCanvasHeight =20;
    private int mCanvasWidth = 20;
    private Paint mLinePaint;
    private int mPaintCounter = 0;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Boolean m_bDead = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    private Boolean m_bDead2 = Boolean.valueOf(true);
    private Boolean m_bRun = Boolean.valueOf(true);
    private Boolean m_bSleep = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    private int m_iScaler =20;
    private int counter = 0;
    /**
     * Instance the Thread
     * All the parameters i handled by the cDrawer class
     * @param paramContext
     * @param paramHandler
     * @param arg4
     */
    public CDrawThread(SurfaceHolder paramContext, Context paramHandler, Handler arg4)
    {
      mSurfaceHolder = paramContext;
      mLinePaint = new Paint();
      mLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      mLinePaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
      mLinePaint = new Paint();
      mLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      mLinePaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 255);
      mBackPaint = new Paint();
      mBackPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      mBackPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
      mBuffer = new short[2048];
      mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    }

    /**
     * Allow you to change the size of the waveform displayed on the screen
     * Or scale of you so will
     * @return returns a new scale value
     */
   /* public int ChangeSensitivity()
    {
      m_iScaler = (5 + m_iScaler);
      if (m_iScaler > 20)
        m_iScaler = 1;
      return m_iScaler;
    }*/

    public Boolean GetDead()
    {
      return m_bDead;
    }

    public Boolean GetDead2()
    {
      return m_bDead2;
    }

    public Boolean GetSleep()
    {
      return m_bSleep;
    }

    public void SetDead2(Boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      m_bDead2 = paramBoolean;
    }

    public void SetSleeping(Boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      m_bSleep = paramBoolean;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate and draws the line
     * @param Canvas to draw on, handled by cDrawer class
     */
    public void doDraw(Canvas paramCanvas)
    {
      if (mCanvasHeight == 1)
        mCanvasHeight = paramCanvas.getHeight();
      paramCanvas.drawPaint(mBackPaint); 
      /**
       * Set some base values as a starting point
       * This could be considerd as a part of the calculation process
       */
      int height = paramCanvas.getHeight();
      int BuffIndex = (mBuffer.length / 2 - paramCanvas.getWidth()) / 2;
      int width = paramCanvas.getWidth();
      int mBuffIndex = BuffIndex;
      int scale = height / m_iScaler;
      int StratX = 0;
      if (StratX >= width)
      {
        paramCanvas.save();
        return;
      }
    int cu1 = 0;
    /**
     * Here is where the real calculations is taken in to action
     * In this while loop, we calculate the start and stop points
     * for both X and Y
     * 
     * The line is then drawer to the canvas with drawLine method
     */
    while (StratX < width -1)
    {
      int StartBaseY = mBuffer[(mBuffIndex - 1)] / scale;

      int StopBaseY = mBuffer[mBuffIndex] / scale;
      if (StartBaseY > height / 2)
      {
          StartBaseY = 1 + height / 2;
        int checkSize = height / 2;
        if (StopBaseY <= checkSize)
            return;
        StopBaseY = 2 + height / 2;
      }

        int StartY = StartBaseY + height / 2;
        int StopY = StopBaseY + height / 2;
        paramCanvas.drawLine(StratX, StartY, StratX +1, StopY, mLinePaint);
        cu1++;
        mBuffIndex++;
        StratX++;
        int checkSize_again = -1 * (height / 2);
        if (StopBaseY >= checkSize_again)
          continue;
        StopBaseY = -2 + -1 * (height / 2);
      }
    }

    public Boolean getRun()
    {
      return m_bRun;
    }

    /**
     * Updated the Surface and redraws the new audio-data
     */
    public void run()
    {
      while (true)
      {
        if (!m_bRun.booleanValue())
        {
          m_bDead = Boolean.valueOf(true);
          m_bDead2 = Boolean.valueOf(true);
          System.out.println("Goodbye Drawthread");
          return;
        }
        Canvas localCanvas = null;
        try
        {
          localCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
          synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
          {
              if (localCanvas != null) 
            doDraw(localCanvas);

        }
        }
        finally
        {
          if (localCanvas != null)
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(localCanvas);
        }
      }
    }

    public void setBuffer(short[] paramArrayOfShort)
    {
      synchronized (mBuffer)
      {
        mBuffer = paramArrayOfShort;
        return;
      }
    }

    public void setRun(Boolean paramBoolean)
    {
      m_bRun = paramBoolean;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
    {
      synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
      {
        mCanvasWidth = paramInt1;
        mCanvasHeight = paramInt2;
        mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, paramInt1, paramInt2, true);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CDrawThread.run() method you are drawing as fast as the device can, so the easiest solution is to first determine the interval which you wish to update your graph (e.g. update once every 16 ms for 60fps) and for each frame:

1. Record the start time
2. Do the drawing
3. Subtract the desired update interval by the amount of time spent on drawing, and sleep for that amount of time

e.g.(psudo code, use at your own peril):

```
private static final int INTERVAL = 16;

public void run()
    {
      while (true)
      {
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();  //<<< record redraw start time
        if (!m_bRun.booleanValue())
        {
          m_bDead = Boolean.valueOf(true);
          m_bDead2 = Boolean.valueOf(true);
          System.out.println("Goodbye Drawthread");
          return;
        }
        Canvas localCanvas = null;
        try
        {
          localCanvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
          synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
          {
              if (localCanvas != null) 
            doDraw(localCanvas);

        }
        }
        finally
        {
          if (localCanvas != null)
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(localCanvas);
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(INTERVAL - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)); //<<< sleep
      }
    }
```